# Luarocks: 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, lua

I'm fairly new to Linux and am having some problems installing `luarocks`. I keep getting the error `E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-27.50_amd64.deb 404 Not Found`.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install luarocks`, `sudo apt-get install luarocks --fix-missing` and `sudo apt-get install luarocks update` through Terminal but have not been able to fix the issue.

I have also tried to look for the `linux` folder under `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/` but it doesn't look like it's there although there are a few folders along the lines of `linux...` under `l/`.

Is there a way to fix this issue or download `luarocks` from some place else (`luarocks.org` seems to timeout for me)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Luarocks` is part of the universe repository - from the Dash, open `Software & Updates`, then in the Ubuntu tab, make sure the Universe repository is selected (see picture below).  To install from the terminal, execute `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install luarocks`, or install from the Ubuntu Software Center, by searching for `luarocks`

[image]

Comment: Hi Charles, a fact that I glanced over is that I'm running this via a VM. When I go into the `Software & Updates` application, I can't see the extra stuff under `Installable from CD-ROM/DVD`. I am trying the `sudo apt-get update` method now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've updated your package index files lately, maybe some of the files you're looking for have been removed or renamed from the source, hence the "file not found" error. Try an `sudo apt-get update` first.

Or maybe the particular source (us.archive.ubuntu.com) doesn't have that file for some reason, if update doesn't work you could try switching to a different source/mirror? The Software & Updates program/settings can change those, and like Charles Green mentioned make sure you've got the universe checked. Those settings can also be changed directly in the files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` if you're feeling adventurous (though make a backup first just in case)

And when new to linux I preferred using Synaptic for searching & installing, easier than a terminal for looking through results with multiple windows & scrollbars imo.

Comment: The `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install luarocks` works well.