# Luarocks version

Tags: package-management, lua

I'm new to Linux and am attempting install the newest `luarocks` version. I'm currently running version `2.0.8` (after running `sudo apt-get update`) which isn't sufficient for some of my needs. Is there a way to specify the version to install? (Also: I'm running this Linux version through a VM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you got Luarocks from [the previous question](https://askubuntu.com/a/554800/283721), but you want a newer version.  I checked the Luarocks homepage, and found [their instructions](http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Unix) to be pretty good, and did the install on a VM in my home machine - it worked!

Here's the steps:

1)  Download the newest version of Luarocks from the download page at http://luarocks.org/releases/.  Get the file `luarocks-2.2.0.tar.gz`

2)  In the `~/Downloads` directory, where I am assuming your webbrowser placed the `tar.gz` file, you will need to unpack file file.

Open a terminal windows (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and first ensure that you have the tools to build programs:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now change to the download directory, extract the Luarocks source files and change to their directory:

```
cd downloads
tar -xvf luarocks-2.2.0.tar.gz
cd luarocks-2.2.0
```

Down for the configure, build and update"

```
./configure
make build
sudo make install
```

You done!  If you enter `luarocks` at this point, it will confirm that you are on version 2.2.0

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks again. Worked perfectly. This should also help in future if I need to install other packages.

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is no possibility to specify a Version. But you can use

> sudo apt-get upgrade

to update all your packages to the newest Version, luarocks too.
And if you dont have luarocks installed yet, you can do it by typing:

> sudo apt-get install luarocks

That should installiert the newest Version, which is available in the ubuntu package sources.

Comment: If there's no newer version of luarocks available, then `apt-get upgrade` would be useless at best, and could break what's working now at worst. Upgrading things like the kernel could cause problems, and I wouldn't do it for zero gain.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "luarocks ubuntu" brings up the packages.ubuntu.com website, where you can see what versions of programs are on what ubuntu's... Precise has version 2.0.8-2 ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/luarocks ), trusty & utopic have 2.0.9-1, vivid has 2.2.0+dfsg-1 ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/luarocks ). Each new & older version is (currently) in the top-right "[lucid][precise]..." links on each page, and under the "Download luarocks" heading in the bottom left you can download the .deb files(s)

You might not have enabled the "backport" or "romeo/proposed" packages in the Software Sources, they might enable a newer version. And if there are multiple versions available you can use "=version" with `apt-get install package=version` or using Synaptic "Package -> Force Version" and "Lock version" to keep a particular package from being changed.

If you're running linux in a VM anyway it might not be hard to download & run vivid.

Or you could try downloading the newer .deb package file(s) from the websites above, and install from the command line with `dpkg -i` though they may require some other upgraded packages that aren't in your current ubuntu, which you may also need to try to download & upgrade manually.